# Bind() returns -1 in my machine while in others run properly

Tags: c, sockets, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint and I am trying to develop a server side application that will listen to a specific port. I tried setting the port to using `htons(0)` but still same issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

float calculator(char *calculation);

extern int errno;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int clientaddrlen, listenfd, connectfd, bytes_rcvd, listen_queue_size=1;
  short int port_no;
  char readBuff[1000];
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr, clientaddr;
  pid_t  childpid;
  int status;
  char sendBuff[1025];

  if(argc!=3){
    printf("Usage Format: ./server -p <PortNumber>\n");
    printf("Sample Run: ./server -p 2000\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  port_no = atoi(argv[argc-1]);
  printf("Server running at port #%d\n", port_no);

  // Create server socket.
  if ( (listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create server socket! errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Server socket created\n");
  // Bind (attach) this process to the server socket.
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(port_no);
  errno = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  if(errno < 0){
    printf("Server bind failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }
```

Given that my code runs on other machines I suppose something is wrong with my system. The error I am getting is

```
Server bind failure errno -1: Unknown error -1
```

This is right after the bind syscall which for some reason returns -1 in my System. Is there something from my system that causes this issue?

Comment: What port number are you attempting to use? Why didn't you bother to remove the dozens of lines after the call to `bind()` that apparently aren't relevant?

Comment: @BillLynch edited my answer, I tried with different port numbers and also with htons(0) and it still crashes

Comment: Is is not good idea to change your question significantly. Due to this some comment(s) and/or answer(s) might become un-understandable!

Comment: OT: `short int port_no;` will not store values `> 0x7ff` correctly. Use `unsigned short int` (or just `int`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using errorno wrong. It is set internally in the `bind()` function and I need to set a different variable to store the return value of `bind()`.

So after changing my code to :

```
 int result = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  if(result < 0)
    {
      printf("Server bind failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
    }
```

I found the true `errno` which was 13.

Errorno 13 Stands for `Permission denied`.

As it turns out in my system ports from under `1080` are reserved for root and this is why I was getting an error. While in other systems it has to be over 1024. I do not know why `htons(0)` gave an error but when I changed my port to `2000` instead of `1025` it worked. In order to use ports under 1080 I had to run the app using `sudo`.

Comment: It's ports less or equal 1024 (not 1080) which require priviledged rights to use them.

Comment: I do not know why but I tried 1025-1079 and it did not work either on my system

Comment: @alk add my answer in yours so I can accept it and I will delete this one. You deserve it because I found the error because of you

Comment: I helped, but you found the root cause yourself and with this provided the correct answer, which btw you could also accept.

Comment: @alk two days must pass before I accept myself :P but shouldn't I edit my question with correct errorno code so future viewers of the question would not read wrong code for their software?

Comment: Please see my comment on "how to update/edit/add to" one's question below my answer.

Comment: I think it's proper now

Answer (score 2):

`bind()` sets  `errno` internally in case of failure. Do not overwrite it.

From [man bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

So this

```
  errno = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  if(errno < 0){
    printf("Server bind failure errno %i: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }
```

shall look something like:

```
  int result = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  if(result < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server bind failure errno %i: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

or even better:

```
  int result = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof servaddr);
  if(result < 0) {
    perror("Server - bind() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

Note: Error messages shall go to Standard Error Output.

Comment: I did not know errno is set internally. Edited my code with new information and new errno

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: I rolled back the update of your code. If updating your question, leave the original question intact.

Comment: this got a bit confusing, I had one mistake in my code that you pointed out but the problem was being cause by using wrong port number, how do we fix this? :P

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: Just **add** the corrected code as part of an addtion to your question. However just leave the original code as it is.

Comment: oh, ok. I will do that instead. i believe you are right

Comment: I added it in my answer. I think it suits better there as it was part of the answer since it was wrong code.